# Rails Format Nil Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm trying to format dates in a Rails view.

```
<td><%= l order.ship_date, :format => :long %></td>
```

This doesn't work if the date is nil:

```
Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given.
```

What's the best "Rails" solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a failsafe if the object is nil:

```
<td><%= l(order.ship_date, :format => :long) if order.ship_date %></td>
```

If you want to display something in case it's nil:

```
<td><%= order.ship_date ? l(order.ship_date, :format => :long) : "Some text" %></td>
```

Comment: In my case, I am using a `text_field` and the failsafe works fine. Thanks! The result is: `<%= f.text_field :due_date, :value => (l(order.due_date) if order.due_date.present?) %>`

Answer (score 10):

Three options:

1) Make sure you never have a nil date. Depends on the product you're trying to create, but in many cases it wouldn't make sense to have a nil date displayed. If, for your product, nil dates are reasonable, this won't work.

2) Write view code everywhere to hide the nil:

```
<%= order.ship_date ? l(order.ship_date, :format => :long) : 'Date unavailable' %>
```

3) Write a helper function to do this for you:

```
def display_date(date, message='Date unavailable')
  date ? l(date, :format => :long) : message
end
```

Then all you have to do in each place you want this date treatment is to say:

```
<%= display_date(order.ship_date) %>
```

Comment: I really like the helper method, it's much shorter, especially when you have an application with a lot of dates.